# Python: Why is my base64 filename encode not matching what it should be?

Tags: python, base64

I have a base64 situation in Python I can't quite figure out -- when I run my script:

```
import rebus
import os

# Set directory
os.chdir('/Users/Ryan/')

# Filename from folder
filename = 'Ryan20160708.txt'

# Create the base64 of the filename
filenameenc = rebus.urlsafe_b64encode(filename)
filebase64 = filenameenc.rstrip()

# Print these for developer
print("Your filename is: " + filename)
print("The base64 encoded filename is: " + filebase64)
```

I get the following results:

```
Your filename is: Ryan20160708.txt
The base64 encoded filename is: UnlhbjIwMTYwNzA4LnR4dAoK
```

The larger script of this is used in an API post that I kept getting `500` errors back on. And that's when I looked more closely at the base64 name and realized it doesn't match with things like on https://www.base64encode.org/ which gives back `UnlhbjIwMTYwNzA4LnR4dA==` instead of `UnlhbjIwMTYwNzA4LnR4dAoK`. Just off in the last couple characters.

Only thing I noticed is that when I put in my base64 into the site and have it decode back to the file name, it comes back with the correct filename (`Ryan20160708.txt`) but it has two line breaks underneath it. Though I'm already stripping any additional whitespace from it with `rstrip()` -- so I'm pretty stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You noticed that you're calling `rstrip()` on the encoded text, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the PyPI on it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rebus/0.2

You'll see that rebus is used to:

> Generate base64-encoded strings consisting of alphanumeric symbols
>   only.

I doubt this is what you want if you're actually looking for base64 encoding.  You probably just want base64 like:

```
import base64
import os

# Set directory
os.chdir('/Users/Ryan/')

# Filename from folder
filename = 'Ryan20160708.txt'

# Create the base64 of the filename
filenameenc = base64.b64encode(filename)
filebase64 = filenameenc.rstrip()

# Print these for developer
print("Your filename is: " + filename)
print("The base64 encoded filename is: " + filebase64)
```

Which will give you

```
Your filename is: Ryan20160708.txt
The base64 encoded filename is: 'UnlhbjIwMTYwNzA4LnR4dA=='
```